# How to get a range of serial numbers based on the movement type?

Tags: serialization, sap-erp

I'm trying to figure out how to perform the task in object.
I want to get serial numbers from range A (internal) when I perform a Goods Receipt (101, 501) in storage location X. After quality checks, materials are transferred to storage location B via 311. After the 311 movement I want to change serials and get the new ones from another range (external).

I already defined ranges and I'm already posting GR with serials from range A. I have to figure out how to tell to SAP to get serials from the second range after posting the 311.

Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Serial numbers are assigned in popup dialog during goods movement [if they are mandatory](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_46c/helpdata/en/4d/2b8e7643ad11d189410000e829fbbd/content.htm), otherwise you should go to special dialog *Goto->Serial Number*. Assignment of external numbers could be done in this way:

1. Go to *SPRO->SAP Customizing Implementation Guide->Plant Maintenance and Customer Service->Master Data in Plant Maintenance and Customer Service->Technical Objects->Serial Number Management* and define profile with `MMSL` procedure or use existing one
2. Assign some equipment category (or create your custom one in OIET transaction) to your Serial Number profile
3. Go to *SPRO->SAP Customizing Implementation Guide->Plant Maintenance and Customer Service->Master Data in Plant Maintenance and Customer Service->Technical Objects->Equipment->Equipment Categories->Define Number Ranges* and assign your previously created number range to your equipment category
4. **[optional]** Also you can go to `S_ALR_87000304` tcode and assign default equipment category which will be used for serial number assignment if system cannot find equipment category from the profile.

Comment: Hi Suncatcher, thank you for your answer. I already performed the customizing step that you listed but unfortunately I can't work in this way: Basically i have 1 equipment category and the discrimination between range of serial numbers is the SAP movement: 101 ==> get internal, 311 ==> get external.

Comment: @rikymiami, try to set Serial Number Usage to Optional in MMSL procedure in your profile settings. That will exclude automatic profile assignment and you would be able to assign external number yourself via _Goto -> Serial number_